# how to start postgresql server on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1

I had just installed a PostgreSQL 9.1 on the Ubuntu 12.04 server (hosted by Amazon EWS).When I tried to launch the **psql** command, the following error message shows up.

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

After searching on the web, I found I have to start the Server before using it. By following this **[initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/creating-cluster.html)** link, I still cannot use the postgresql database. Are there any further work (like configuration) should I do to start the server ?

I tried to start the service : **service postgresql start**
Another error message shows :

> No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"

Comment: `initdb` only initializes the database, does not start the service. You should be able to start the service with the `service` command.

Comment: @datasage Yes I tried to start the server with **service** like following : service postgresql start. Another error message jumps out. I updated my post.

Comment: 'How to start postgres' and 'How to purge postgres' are not duplicates.

Answer (score 19):

I received this message running a new installation of Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu 11.04.  The full message was:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
Error: Cannot stat /var/run/postgresql
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

Turned out that the /var/run/postgresql directory did not exist, and it is in that directory where it was attempting to create a file with the process ID.  I created the directory as root and made the "postgres" user the owner, and I was able to start the server.

Further explanation found here:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21044.1326496507@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: I has the same error I fix it with this command
    sudo pg_createcluster 9.1 main --start