# PostgreSQL - WSL : won't init

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i'm currently developping a Django server where i need a database, Sqlite3 don't seem to handle well my need so i'm trying to use PostgreSQL instead. I'm devellopping on Windows but the server will run on a Linux system once development is done, so i'm trying to use WSL to fit the expected result.

```
wsl -l -v  
NAME            STATE           VERSION  
Ubuntu-22.04    Running         1
```

I also updated to WSL2, same issue.

My issue is that i can't start the database :

```
# sudo service postgresql start
No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

What i've done so far :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib

// it s installed
> psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.2 (Ubuntu 14.2-1ubuntu1)

// no service currently running
> ps aux| grep postgres
root       583  0.0  0.0  15044  1280 tty3     S    08:42   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres

// no cluster ?!?
> sudo service postgresql start
No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"

// indeed no cluster are created by default 
> pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file

// but i can t create one
> pg_createcluster 14.2 main
Error: no initdb program for version 14.2 found

> sudo pg_createcluster 14 main
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 14/main ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main --auth-local peer --auth-host scram-sha-256 --no-instructions
Can't exec "/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/initdb": Permission denied at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 86.
Error: Could not open /etc/postgresql/14/main/start.conf for writing: Permission denied
Can't exec "/bin/sh": Permission denied at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 617.
Error: initdb failed
```

I also tried : [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552861/postgresql-no-postgresql-clusters-exist-see-man-pg-createcluster-during-ser)

```
> sudo service --status-all
// ...
[ - ]  postgresql
// ...

> sudo ps aux | grep postgres
root       769  0.0  0.0  15044  1284 tty3     S    08:48   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

I didn't really understand this link : [Change some config file that i can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281777/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu-12-04)
And this one that only proposed to reformat my disk.. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962002/postgres-cannot-create-cluster-as-root)

Comment: I don't know why you are referring to a link for Amazon ubuntu version 12 - that doesn't seem relevant. Are you sure you don't need to be running under wsl 2 for service daemons like postgresql?

Comment: I wasn't aware of such limitation in wsl, tho idk if it's similar but both Redis and Mosquitto seem to run fine on wsl.

Comment: Well, one of the key differences IIRC that WSL1 files are mapped from the Windows filesystem and subject to the usual issues with virus-checkers interfering etc. Don't take my word for it though - I only played around with WSL a little bit a couple of years ago.

Comment: @RichardHuxton updated to WSL2, same issue, i linked the amazon ubuntu because it was the exact same error on a ubuntu based system so it semmed similar enough to me

Comment: I followed this https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-on-wsl2-for-windows-install-and-setup/ to setup postgresql in wsl.

Comment: Thank you very much, it work with a few steps following your link, i'll format everything and accept the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Mark's [Link](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-on-wsl2-for-windows-install-and-setup/) i was able to find a solution.

1. It seems that WSL2 is required
2. I tried 2 wsl distro :

   - [Ubuntu-22.04](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-2204-lts/9PN20MSR04DW?hl=en-us&gl=US) -> Didn't work even with the guide, maybe it would work on a fresh install.
   - [Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10#1-overview) -> fresh install worked

```bash
# Create the file repository configuration:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

# Import the repository signing key:
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package lists:
sudo apt-get update

# Install the latest version of PostgreSQL.
# If you want a specific version, use 'postgresql-12' or similar instead of 'postgresql':
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```